# How to validate against multiple base ldap dns in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap

Currently I have one base dn where I create users and authenticate my ldap. How do I do this for multiple base dns where I need to check in a base dn based on my role. Below is my current code.

```
ldap.urls= ldap://localhost:10389/
ldap.base.dn= ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
ldap.user.dn.pattern = cn={0}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapEnabled)) {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern)
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls+ldapBaseDn);
    }
}
```

But I want to do this for multiple 2 base dns.     `ldap.base.dn= ou=test1,dc=example,dc=com,`     `ldap.base.dn= ou=test2,dc=example,dc=com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the way I take the `userDNSPatters` `varchar`. Below is the modified version

```
ldap.urls= ldap://localhost:10389/
ldap.base.dn= dc=example,dc=com
ldap.user.dn.pattern.test1 = cn={0},ou=test1
ldap.user.dn.pattern.test2 = cn={0},ou=test2

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    if(Boolean.parseBoolean(ldapEnabled)) {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
                .userDnPatterns(ldapUserDnPattern1, ldapUserDnPattern2)
                .contextSource()
                .url(ldapUrls+ldapBaseDn);
    }
}
```

This way it searches both the `ou's`